# Panda Data Manipulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Using Panda's how could I transform the first screenshot into the third screenshot? I'm somewhat new to Pandas and i'm still getting used to it. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please replace your screenshots with actual tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your second dataframe in your upper screenshot is called `df`, this should do:

```
df.set_index('Name').stack().reset_index(level=0)
```

Comment: Thank you .That worked. Do you know how I would approach transforming screenshot 1 into screenshot 2? I figured out how to extract the column value and the value of a particular cell but I don't know how to loop through all the rows. Thank you!

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Thank you!